# How to run gkrellm in the taskbar in Openbox?

Tags: openbox, cpu-usage

How do you get *gkrellm* to run in the taskbar, in a system tray or dock, in Openbox?

I've come across lots of web pages that say it's possible, but I haven't seen an explanation of how to do it.

Thw *-w* switch:

```
gkrellm -w
```

only makes *gkrellm* run as an always-on-top window in the upper left corner of the screen. Is there a config file or something that I need to modify?

I'm running version 2.3.6-RCl of *gkrellm* and the taskbar is version 0.12-git-dirty of *tint2.*

---

BTW, I'm just looking for a CPU/memory/disk/network monitor to run in a taskbar under Openbox. If there's a simpler or better way than *gkrellm,* I'd like to hear about it, especially if getting *gkrellm* to work is going to be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Here the  necessary steps to run `gkrellm` as a dockapp.

First make sure your Openbox configuration has a ´` element.
The configuration is usually under

```
~/.config/openbox/rc.xml
```

or for Lubuntu under

```
~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Edit the file and check for a dock element under the root element `<openbox_config>`. There should be something like

```
<dock>
  <!-- (Top|Bottom)(Left|Right|)|Top|Bottom|Left|Right|Floating -->
  <position>Left</position>
  <floatingX>0</floatingX>
  <floatingY>0</floatingY>
  <noStrut>yes</noStrut>
  <!-- 'Above', 'Normal', or 'Below' -->
  <stacking>Above</stacking>
  <!-- 'Vertical' or 'Horizontal' -->
  <direction>Vertical</direction>
  <autoHide>yes</autoHide>
  <!-- in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second) -->
  <hideDelay>300</hideDelay>
  <!-- in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second) -->
  <showDelay>300</showDelay>
  <!-- 'Left', 'Middle', 'Right' -->
  <moveButton>Middle</moveButton>
</dock>
```

Reconfigure Openbox

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Run `gkrellm`

```
gkrellm -w
```

When you use the above configuration then ´gkrellm` should now appear when you move your mouse to the middle of your left Desktop boarder.

A description of the configuration options can be found in the [Openbox configuration manual](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration#Dock).

If you have no `<dock>` element in your Openbox configuration `gkrellm` seems to run as you have described it.